Show default value when field access denied
I have a hook_entity_field_access() that allows access to the user picture field in various conditions. When viewing the user, the picture is either present or not present as it should be.
The user picture field has a default image. This shows when no image has been selected or the image has been removed from the user, if access has been allowed.
How can I also show the field default image when access to the user picture field has been denied?
I'm using Drupal 10.2.5.

Access doesn’t sound like the right approach here - no access means the field should not render, including default value, so you’re always going to fighting against the system and undoing/redoing things it would typically do for you. A custom field type, one which contextually renders the default image if your condition is met, might make more sense. Or you could hook into the relevant render contexts, check the #access in the render array, load the field metadata, and manually replace it. The 2nd way is flakier because you have may have to update the code when you add, eg, a new view mode.

Yes, you're right - I am having to find elaborate workarounds, which is what lead me to posting here. Access just seems so right though! :)
Isn't a custom field type overkill for something like this?
I'd like to try the render context approach, but I've not been able find a suitable hook to let me get and alter the render array.

No you're right, access is the right approach here, ignore that other comment I can't have read the post properly first time. Sorry about that. Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but couldn't you just return AccessResult::allowed() for the 'view' $operation specifically in hook_entity_field_access()? It sounds like that field should always show, it'll render the image if populated, default if not, and field edit permissions will stay the same by splitting the operation access

Unfortunately the user picture should only be shown to anonymous users if the viewed user has chosen to make their photo visible. Logged in users can always see it.
You sent me down a different course with the field type suggestion, which has lead me to create a field formatter derived from ImageFormatter. I only have a few view modes, and all used ImageFormatter, so I can switch them all to my formatter. I've got this working with just a few minor bugs to squash.
It's not as reliable as the hook_entity_field_access() approach would have been, but at least it works for my use-case!

Field formatter plugin works, but then of course you could also have just put an "if" in a custom twig template. Something like if access show image 1 else image 2. And then a preprocess function to set the access variable
